# A single big sql table or multiple small sql tables?

Tags: sql-server-2005, aggregate

I'm currently working with MS SQL 2005, and have a table that has 17 columns, and the space that data in each row would take is only a bit less than what is allowed(per row/record) in MS SQL 2005. And it is for sure that I cannot break this up into smaller tables as the data stored in this table is input from excel sheets whose contents I'm not in control of.

Now the point is, that for almost everything on the Website that uses this database, that main table is providing the result sets, and these result sets are previously known. So, which would be better of the two:
a) I make use of the big table every time.
b) I create smaller tables, and depopulate/populate them as soon as data is edited in the big table.

For eg: Excel sheets containing details of products arrive(almost weekly) from various manufacturers, and they are stored in the PRODUCTS(big) table. Now there are queries like:

`SELECT DISTINCT Brand_name, Model_name FROM PRODUCTS`

and

`SELECT DISTINCT Brand_name, Model_name FROM PRODUCTS WHERE Price < 10` and about 10-15 like these.

Now my question is: Should I build already aggregated tables for these things which amount to about 5 more other than the PRODUCTS table, and update them whenever a sheet comes in, or should I just execute all my retrieval queries on the PRODUCTS table?

The PRODUCTS table would contain about 500,000 rows at the max at a time.

Comment: What is the table definition? Are you using fixed length columns when variable length might be better?

Comment: Yes I'm using varchar(n)(this n varies according to the column) for 15 columns, and float for two columns. Haven't really known about variable length columns

Comment: @Anchit - You should be nowhere near the row limit in SQL Server 2005 then (though if the rows are > 8000 bytes they will spill over into row_overflow pages)

Comment: @Martin - Well to be honest, before this day, the table definition was such that if the definition was fully utilized, the row size was definitely going to exceed the row limit(I did not design the table). It is just today I noticed this, also earlier, there were different tables for each manufacturer(about 9 of them, with the same schema), so I integrated them into one table.

Comment: @Martin - And yeah, the website has been running without any problems since the last 6 months, but I agree that the row size is high and it may arise problems if the alloted space is fully utilized, any methods that you'd suggest I could use to reduce the size?

Comment: @Martin - Well, in my first comment what I meant was that some columns have fixed size varchar(500), one has varchar(5000), others are smaller varchars but all of fixed size.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would be inclined to stick with your single table. 500k records isn't overly massive. If you make sure its properly index for the common selects you are using on it you will probably find it is fairly quick.

Try and run some controlled and repeatable tests to see what sort of speed gains you can get with the right indexes.

Comment: Ok, so I'm fairly a n00b in SQL, can you please provide me a link to a good article regarding creating indexes, and yes also, how can I check them speeds? o_0 (sorry for being such a noob)

Comment: Try http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Performance+Tuning/indexcreationguidelines/1389/ it might require free registration to read. Its a great site for all things SQL related.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Just checking out the link.